# How to trigger error when not using wp_reset_postdata();? Why use it if the loop works without it?

Tags: wp-reset-postdata

I have two loops in my code, why do I need to use `wp_reset_postdata();` after each if it doesnt make any difference?

The definition: After looping through a separate query, this function restores the *$post global* to the current post in the main query.

So if I create a query that queries post_types, or categories or anything other than the post type="post_type" (which is the default parameter of the loop) then the `wp_reset_postdata();` restores the post_type to "post_type"?
If so how would that look in code, or is it nonsense that i just wrote?

Regardless can you give me an example of it?

```
        <div class="one-half">
                    <h2>Latest Opinion</h2>
                        <?php // opinion posts loop begins here
                        $opinionPosts = new WP_Query('cat=1&posts_per_page=2');

                        if ($opinionPosts->have_posts()) :
                            while ($opinionPosts->have_posts()) : $opinionPosts->the_post(); ?>
                                <div class="post-item clearfix">
                                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php endwhile;
                            else : // fallback no content message here
                        endif;
                        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div><!-- /one-half -->

        <div class="one-half last">
                    <h2>Latest News</h2>
                        <?php // news posts loop begins here
                        $newsPosts = new WP_Query('cat=23&posts_per_page=2');

                        if ($newsPosts->have_posts()) :
                            while ($newsPosts->have_posts()) : $newsPosts->the_post(); ?>                           
                                <div class="post-item clearfix">
                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                    </div><!-- /post-item -->
                            <?php endwhile;
                            else :  // fallback no content message here
                        endif;
                        wp_reset_postdata();
        </div> <!-- /one-half -->

                    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the point of restoring the context to original state.

Yes, your loops *do* work without reset. But anything that tries to access queried post *after* them will hit leftovers of your custom queries in global variables, rather than post from main query.

In a literal sense the reset after your *first* query in this specific code is redundant, since there is nothing else done and you just proceed to do another query. However it is a good idea to keep it, because in case of *future* changes to the code the order of things might very well might change and this will suddenly cause an issue unnecessarily.

Comment: What would I need to add  to it in order for it to be actually useful?
can you give me a bit more specifc example?

Comment: It _is_ actually useful — it prevents your queries from leaving overridden global state after them. Without it any template tag call after them would produce unexpected and invalid results.